# SQL Joining another table based on the ID of the initial table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I really just can't seem to grasb the sytanx of SQL Joins, etc ... so I'm needing some help with this (which I think is quite simple)

I'm querying `bid_tag` as follows:

```
SELECT paid_date, term, pet_id FROM bid_tag WHERE active = 1
```

And I need to use the `pet_id` to then grab some information from another table `wp_postmeta`, where the table is actually in a `meta_key` `meta_value` structure (WordPress) ...

So I need to grab the `meta_value` of `meta_key` "bid_name", for example... amongst other values.

```
TABLE
id | meta_key | meta_value
1    bid_name    Max
```

That `ID` is the same `ID` that I need to connect the initial table to...

I really appreciate it!

Comment: can you post some sample data and then the expected result?

Comment: I added some more information.

Comment: `... from bid_tag join wp_postmeta on pet_id=id ...` would be a join condition that connects bid_tag with wp_postmeta and you can then select the meta_key and meta_value for which the id is the same as pet_id.

Answer (score 0):

Join on both the `id` and the `meta_key` to select your desired value. If you want values that go with other keys in the meta table as well, one way is to join multiple times:

```
SELECT bt.paid_date, bt.term, bt.pet_id,
    bn.meta_value as bidname,
    bo.meta_value as bidother
FROM bid_tag bt
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta bn on bn.id = bt.pet_id and bn.meta_key = 'bid_name'
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta bo on bo.id = bt.pet_id and bo.meta_key = 'bid_other'
WHERE bt.active = 1
```

If the values won't necessarily be present in the meta table, use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead and it will return `null` for whatever is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how your query would go:

```
SELECT B.meta_key, B.meta_value, A.pet_id
FROM bid_tag A
JOIN wp_postmeta B
ON B.id = A.pet_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

there're some ways to use join: 
1)use `inner join` or equally just `join`:

```
select 
  --some columns
from bid_tag
join wp_postmeta on
  bid_tag.pet_id = wp_postmeta.id
where
  wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'bid_name'
```

The result will have only that records which `pet_id` exists in `wp_postmeta`. The other will be omitted. And if `wp_postmeta` have a couple of records with the same `id` (and exists `pet_id` equal this `id`) then you'll get a couple records with this pet_id (**BUT** with different `meta_key` and `meta_value`).
2)use `left join`:

```
select 
  --some columns
from bid_tag
left join wp_postmeta on
  bid_tag.pet_id = wp_postmeta.id
where
  wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'bid_name'
```

In this case behavior will be the same except one thing - even if there aren't any `id` for a `pet_id` the result will contain record from `wp_postmeta` with this `pet_id`. But `meta_key` and `meta_value` in this case will be `null`.